# Android golang bind refresh *.aar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, go

I am importing an aar file using the new module > import JAR or AAR package option. Initially I was able call a method from my library. However after updating the library and running Gomobile bind again, I can't figure out how to update the aar file. The new methods are not shown after updating the .aar file manually.
Importing again causes "Project already contains subproject with name mobilelib".

Android Studio 2.2.3
How do I refresh the .aar file?

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testing.testgolanglib"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':mobilelib')
}
```

mobilelib

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('mobilelib.aar'))
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir{
            dirs '/Users/abc/projects/go/src/com.abc/mobilelib'
        }

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory,  you have two options:

1. Run `gomobile bind` manually each time you change the library, then copy the AAR file from your Go source directory to the `mobilelib` directory, replacing the old AAR file. And, finally rebuild the project;
2. Use the `org.golang.mobile.bind` Gradle plugin, that is supposed to do all of this work for you.

But, as far as I know, the plugin is not up-to-date with the latest Gradle tools and doesn't work properly.

Comment: I tried using the golang.mobile.bind plugin but I'm not sure how to configure it properly. I keep getting the following gradle error

    :mobilelib:gobind FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mobilelib:gobind'.
    > Cannot get property 'classpath' on null object

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --     debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 0.427 secs

Comment: I know, this plugin stopped functioning after the update of the Gradle tools. This is why I had to fall back to using the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by simplifying a new function on golang. I used struct with supported by gomobile data types to return the result, when I simplified the function (encoded the result into a simple string), everything worked.